# How to do subset in a loop using a factor and assign names to subsets of data. Both factor and names have to take the index value

Tags: r

I have a DF which I need to break into subsets based on some columns of the DF that contain the factors. Something like this:

```
value (numeric) factor 1 (factor)   factor 2 (factor)
23  1   FR
45  1   FR
33  1   ER
1345    2   TY
2325    2   TY
221 3   TY
11  4   FR
2234    4   FR
```

I can do :

```
subset1 <- subset(DF,factor 1 =="1" & factor =="FR")
```

but I want to do it in a loop.. the name of the subset has to concatenate the index of the loop (e.g., i) with the name and the value of factors have to be structured in a way that can be passed as index. Basically I want to do the subsetting in a loop.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: That is, don't tell us how you want it done, tell us what you what to accomplish. One reason you're not getting answers is that nobody wants to tell you how to write a loop to make a bunch of new variables with certain names because that's almost certainly not a good way to accomplish your task. But we can't tell for sure unless you tell us the big picture of what you're trying to do.